Jack Russell (°2018) diagnosed with cystinuria. What are the best things to treat this?
Victor (°02-07-2018; male; JackRussel Terrier), my dog, is suffering from (recurring) cystine stones.

02/2024 - Victor urinated at weird places (in-house), his urine flow changed to more frequent and bursts of pee.

03/2024 - At the vet, Victor was diagnosed with cystinuria.

Treatment: castration , surgical removal of stones, and changing to a strict and specialized diet Royal Canin - URINARY S/O.
Afterwards, we noticed that Victor was way more active, and the force of the flow he peed with was strong, and consistent.


(in between)-- we noticed that Victor started peeing more in bursts.
Just before the second surgery (CFR. 19/10/2204, in the next paragraph), I noticed that a reddish color in one of his pees.

18/10/2024

At 12:00 → Victor is unable to pee. Starts trembling &shaking.
At 12:30 → Victor @ Vet: sondage was done to remove the pressure from the full bladder. During the sondage, several obstructions (i.e., stones) were blocking the urinal tract. These were pushed back into the bladder, allowing the urine to flow out of the penis.
This was just to stabilize, a surgery was needed.


19/20/2024
The vet performed a surgery to remove all stones from the bladder.
These stones are sent to a specialized lab (currently awaiting the results).
The urine that was extracted during the surgery showed prevalence of cystine crystals only.


Question
Given the relatively small time between these two instances (I.e., 03/2024 and 19/20/2024). What else can I do to maximally help in preventing this to happen that frequently?
Let me know if more information is needed, please ask.
I appreciate all of your help.
